# Is the statement $v^Tw =w^Tv$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transpose

I have two vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Is the statement $v^Tw =w^Tv$ true?

In my opinion yes, because both are a single number, and this should be the same.

Let $v:= \left( \begin{matrix} x\\y\\z \end{matrix} \right)$ and $w:=\left( \begin{matrix} a\\b\\c \end{matrix} \right) $.

Then we get $$v^Tw = \left( \begin{matrix} x & y & z \end{matrix} \right)  \left( \begin{matrix} a \\b \\c \end{matrix} \right) = xa+yb+zc = ax+by+cz = \left( \begin{matrix} a&b&c \end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} x\\y\\z \end{matrix} \right)= w^Tv$$
because the multiplication is commutative.

Is this ok?

Comment: Note that $$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x&y&z\end{pmatrix}$$ is a 3x3-matrix. You have to transpose both matrices in order to get a number.

Comment: It’s _almost_ correct, per @Calculix comment above: that last matrix product is equal to $wv^T$, not $w^Tv$, nor is it equal to $ax+by+cy$, since that’s a scalar and the product that you have is a $3\times3$ matrix. You’ve also got $yz$ where you probably meant $cz$.

Comment: Technically you would need to draw in some ellipses to make this proof strictly apply to $\Bbb R^n$ and not $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct :).
This is actually a way to define the (usual) dot product in $\mathbb{R}^n$ : $v\cdot w := v^T w = w^T v$. (so remember this identity! It comes up a lot in linear algebra ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is ok. 
Your apprach is right .
It is just the commutativity of $\mathbb R$.